# how to get list of tables which were inserted into or updated in last one hour in sql server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database

We have a java application that updates / inserts values into the database.

we need to identify the tables it touches during an operation.

is there a way to find the list of tables the code updated/ inserted in the last one hour by a query ?

the database is sql server.

Answer (score 1):

To get list of record for the past hour(x) from specific table

```
select * from table_name where Col_name> DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
```

to return list of tables modify past few hours

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'dbName') and last_user_update> DATEADD(HOUR, -4, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score -1):

I would simply do a compareTo(). But you'll have to do a timestamp for the database.

```
LocalTime thisSec;

for (;;) {
thisSec = LocalTime.now();

// implementation of display code is left to the reader
display(thisSec.getHour(), thisSec.getMinute(), thisSec.getSecond());
if (thisSec >= myDB.row(id).timestamp+1)
      System.out.println(myDb.row(id));
}
```

Something like that anyway
    If you have a myDb.timestamp.row, that considers hrs,mins,secs, and you make `.timestamp` that time, this should work.

[JAVA docs on db interactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlstructured.html)